# Verifying that message came from a specific app/end point

Tags: android, security, ssl, cryptography, drm

I'm trying to build a secure system for transmitting data from a client Android app to a web server running PHP.

What I want to do is ensure that the system is cryptographically secure in such a way that the messages from the app can be verified as being actually from the app itself, rather than being from a devious user who may have written a custom script or perhaps using cURL in order to game the system.

There are a number of use cases for this kind of verification, for example:-

- If an app contains an advert from which you gather metrics, you would want to verify that the click data is being sent from the app rather than from a malicious user who has figured out your API and is sending dummy data.
- The app might have a multiple-choice survey and again, you would want to ensure that the survey results are being collected from the app.
- The app is collecting GPS traces and you want to ensure that the data is being sent from the app itself.

In each of these cases, you would want to ensure that the origin of the messages is the app itself, and not just a user who is running a simple script to fake the data.

Some ideas I've considered:-

- **SSL** - Works well for securing the channel and preventing tampering (which fulfils some of the requirements) but still cannot ensure the integrity of the source of the data.
- **Public-key cryptography** - The client app could encrypt the data with a private key and then transmit it to the server where it can be decoded. The problem is that the private key needs to be hardcoded within the app -- the app could be decompiled and the private key extracted and then used to send fake data.
- **Home-made algorithms** - A very similar question to this is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331488/determining-if-a-request-came-from-an-iphone-app) where the solutions only work until "someone figures out your algorithm" -- i.e. not a great solution!
- **[Hash chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain)** - This seemed like a really interesting way of using one-time keys to verify each data payload from the client to server, but again it relies on the app itself not being decompiled, because the password still needs to be stored by the app.

My limited knowledge of cryptography makes me think that it's actually theoretically **impossible** to build a system that would be totally verifiable in this manner, because if we cannot trust the end client or the channel, then there is nothing on which to base any trust... but maybe there's something I've overlooked!

Comment: What about using a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) generated by the server to identify transactions? Use GCM or something to make sure that only a device can receive the nonce.

Comment: Not a bad idea to involve GCM, but we are assuming that there's no other way to receive GCM messages other than via an Android app... Maybe there is (I don't know). Either way, it would be nice if we could come up with a solution (if one exists) that doesn't rely on platform-specific technologies.

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to try security.stackexchange.com. I'm not a crypto expert, but there are plenty over there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950732/security-from-evil-user

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/826/2435).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard, you just need to authenticate the app. You can do this with a simple user and password (over SSL) or use client authentication. In both cases, the credentials need to be in the app, and an attacker can extract them and impersonate the app. You have to leave with it and maybe implement some methods to mitigate it.

You can also authenticate the messages, by having them signed either with an asymmetric key (RSA, etc.) or a symmetric one (HMAC, etc.). A nonce helps against replays, where someone captures a validly signed messages and sends it to your server over and over again. Depending on your protocol, the overhead of using one might be too much.

To protect the credentials, you can have the client generate them and save them in the system `KeyStore`, although it is not quite supported by a public API, see [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html) for some details. This, of course, requires an extra step where you need to send the generated credentials (say, public key) to your server securely which might be tricky to implement properly.

Whatever you do, don't try to invent your own cryptographic algorithm or protocol, use an established one.

Comment: I think the OP wants to prevent a user who *does* have legitimate credentials from using them with a third-party client app, which is not quite the same.

Comment: It doesn't read that way to me, but anyway. Why do people keep closing perfectly valid questions? Because they might be hard to answer? Really?

Comment: 1. The OP referred to hardcoding a key within the app, so even if they implement your suggestion they still have to add DRM to make the key harder to extract. 2. Not sure if that question is directed at me (I did not vote to close as offtopic.  Dupe votes might be justified though.)

Comment: The closing questions thing was not directed at you specifically. I've been seeing a lot of perfectly valid questions lately. ' messages from the app can be verified as being actually from the app itself' in my book means that he wants to authenticate the app. DRM generally refers to tying content to a single (or a small number of devices). 'Content' here might be a key if you read it broadly, but that doesn't change the fact that he wants to authenticate the *app* ('ensure that the origin of the messages is the app itself'). I am not saying I gave the perfect answer, just some ideas.